# R: how to remove repeated elements in a character vector

Tags: r, regex, string

```
s <- "height(female), weight, BMI, and BMI."
```

In the above string, the word BMI is repeated twice. I would like the string to be:

```
"height (female), weight, and BMI."
```

I have tried the following to break the string down into unique parts:

```
> unique(strsplit(s, " ")[[1]])
[1] "height"      "(female),"   "weight,"    "BMI," "and"         "BMI."
```

But since "BMI," and "BMI." are not the same strings, using `unique` does not get rid of one of them.

EDIT: How can I go about moving repeated phrases? (i.e. body mass index instead of BMI)

```
s <- "height (female), weight, weight, body mass index, body mass index." 
s <- stringr::str_replace(s, "(?<=, |^)\\b([()\\w\\s]+),\\s(.*?)((?: and)?(?=\\1))", "\\2") 
> stringr::str_replace(s, "(\\w+)(\\(.*?\\))", "\\1 \\2")
[1] "height (female), weight, body mass index, body mass index."
```

Comment: The rules are not very clear to me. Is the structure of `s` always `"<keyword>, <keyword>, ..., and <keyword>"`? Can a keyword contain commas, whitespaces, the word `"and"`, ...?

Comment: The structure of `s` is always "<keyword>, <keyword>, ..., and <keyword>." Some "<keyword>"s may contain "(male)" or "(female)". Each "<keyword>" is followed by "," and the last <keyword> is preceded by "and"

Comment: Can you provide an example that covers a few more edge cases?  For example, what happens if there are two `height(female)`?  Or does that not happen?

Comment: @andrew_reece that does not happen.

Comment: So the only substring you ever want to remove is `" BMI,"`?  
Like `stringr::str_replace(s, " BMI,", "")`?

Comment: do you want the first instance of the word to be dropped or the 2nd/nth instances to be dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to replace the unwanted duplicates first using a regex like this:

```
(?<=,|^)([()\w\s]+),\s(.*?)((?: and)?(?=\1))
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/XM1hI3/2)

**Explanation**

- `(?<=, |^)\b` front boundary. (`\b` should work too but is not properly anchored that way)
- `([()\w\s]+),` block element
- `\s(.*?)((?: and)?` everything inbetween
- `(?=\1))` repeated element

Code Sample:

```
#install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr)
s <- "height(female), weight, BMI, and BMI."
stringr::str_replace(s, "(?<=, |^)\\b([()\\w\\s]+),\\s(.*?)((?: and)?(?=\\1))", "\\2")
```

Output:

```
[1] "height(female), weight, and BMI."
```

---

Regarding the separation of parts in parenthesis, use another replacement like that:

```
stringr::str_replace(s, "(\\w+)(\\(.*?\\))", "\\1 \\2")
```

Output:

```
[1] "height (female), weight, and BMI."
```

Test and putting things together:

```
s <- c("height(female), weight, BMI, and BMI."
       ,"height(female), weight, whatever it is, and whatever it is."
       ,"height(female), weight, age, height(female), and BMI."
       ,"weight, weight.")
s <- stringr::str_replace(s, "(?<=, |^)\\b([()\\w\\s]+),\\s(.*?)((?: and)?(?=\\1))", "\\2")
stringr::str_replace(s, "(\\w+)(\\(.*?\\))", "\\1 \\2")
```

Output:

```
[1] "height (female), weight, and BMI."      "height (female), weight, and whatever it is."
[3] "weight, age, height (female), and BMI." "weight."
```

Comment: Thank you. When I ran the code, I'm getting `"height(female), weight,and BMI."` i.e. there's space missing between "height" and "(female)", and a space missing between "weight," and "and"

Comment: @Adrian You are right; I made a last minute change when I posted the code and messed it up. Updated.

Comment: Thanks again for the update. I'm currently running into an issue when I use `s <- "height (female), body mass index, body mass index."` i.e. the repeated segment is no longer a single word (BMI) but now a phrase (body mass index). How can I go about handling this case?

Comment: @Adrian when I run that line I get `"height (female), body mass index."` What's wrong with that?

Comment: I've updated my original post with a new string. I'm running `s <- "height (female), weight, weight, body mass index, body mass index."
s <- stringr::str_replace(s, "(?<=, |^)\\b([()\\w\\s]+),\\s(.*?)((?: and)?(?=\\1))", "\\2")
stringr::str_replace(s, "(\\w+)(\\(.*?\\))", "\\1 \\2")`

Answer (score 1):

You can give this regex a try:

```
(\b\w+\b)[^\w\r\n]+(?=.*\1)
```

and replace each match with a blank string

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9eYFxK/4)**

**[Check the Ruby Code](https://regex101.com/r/9eYFxK/4/codegen?language=ruby)**

**Input**

```
height(female), weight, BMI, BMI, BMI, BMI, BMI, BMI, BMI, BMI, BMI, BMI, and BMI.
height(female), weight, BMI, age, and BMI.
```

**Output**

```
height(female), weight, and BMI.
height(female), weight, age, and BMI.
```

**Explanation:**

- `(\b\w+\b)` - matches 1+ occurrences of a word character surrounded by word boundaries and capture it in group 1
- `[^\w\r\n]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character that is neither a word nor a newline character. So, this will match `,`, `.`, or spaces.
- `(?=.*\1)` - positive lookahead to validate that whatever is matched in group 1 must come again later in the string. Only, in that case, the replacement will be made.

**Note**: This will keep the last occurrence of the repeated-words.

Alternatively, you can use [`(\b[^,]+)[, ]+(?=.*\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/9eYFxK/6), if the repeated words contain spaces too.

Comment: I like it but it fails if there are similar substrings: `height(female), weight, whatever this is, and whatever that is.`

Comment: yes because in group 1, i am just allowing continuous word characters `\w+` which disallow spaces. Anyways, it will give the OP an idea :)

Comment: The OP is not clear about that. If it's not the case your answer pretty much fits the bill.

Comment: @Gurman Thanks. What's the exact R code to implement this? `stringr::str_replace(s, "(\b\w+\b)[^\w\r\n]+(?=.*\1)", "")` gives me the error: `Error: '\w' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(\b\w"`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)

s <- "height(female), weight, BMI, and BMI, and more even more BMI."
pieces <- unlist(str_split(s, "\\b"))
non_word <- !grepl("\\w", pieces)

# if you want to keep just the last instance of a duplicated word
non_duped <- !duplicated(pieces, fromLast = TRUE)
paste0(pieces[non_word | non_duped], collapse = "")
#> [1] "height(female), weight, ,  , and  even more BMI."

# if you want to keep just the first instance of a duplicated word
non_duped <- !duplicated(pieces, fromLast = FALSE)
paste0(pieces[non_word | non_duped], collapse = "")
#> [1] "height(female), weight, BMI, and ,  more even  ."
```